# How to save image from another website programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to save image from another website programmatically? Using asp.net c#
for example I wouldlike to create request on google to search something for example beer and from search result save images using asp.net web application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is easy. Crawl page, find url of the image with regex or jQuery for example and pass it as string to method below:

```
private void GetImage(string url)
        {
                    Stream imageStream = new WebClient().OpenRead(url);
                    Image img = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
                    img.Save(@"C:\MyImage.jpg");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to build a "spider" in C#... there is an open source sample project on CodeProject here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ZetaWebSpider.aspx which should help get you going.

Comment: In my case I just need a method to get an image, not all website